# Question Not Favorited When Tapping Favorite in the Android App

Tags: bug, android-app, bookmarks

When I tap the favorite star in the android app for a question I asked, the question is not favorited. Instead a red banner appears at the top that says "Question not favorited."  Is this a known bug?

I'm running **version 1.0.6** of the app

UPDATE: Alternatively, when favoriting a question I did *not* ask, I get the following message

> The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site

The above message occurs with **version 1.0.73** of the app.

Comment: Are you logged in on the site you wanted to favorite the question? Try doing an action that will make you logged in first (e.g. add comment, vote)?

Comment: I deliberately logged out, then in, before favoriting. Does that count?

Comment: That... Should fix the issue... Because I can't repro this on v1.0.73 (I'd say device is irrelevant since it's about API call)

Comment: I log in using my Google account, if that helps.  Also favoriting on the site, within the mobile Chrome browser, works.

Comment: After a) re-flashing my device several times due to an unrelated issue, b) rooting said device and c) logging back into the app (using my Google login) I was able to favorite a question. I'm not adding this process as an answer for obvious reasons, however I am running version 1.0.75 of the app...which may be the fix

Comment: OTOH, this exakt same behavior appeared in Version 1.0.85 on Android 5.0.2 .